# Поднять объект в воздух

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть свойства:

```
float height = 8f,
Force = 0f;
public float force {
    get {
        return Engine;
    }
    set {
        Force = value;
    }
}
```

И метод:

```
private void Lift() {
    var up = 1 - Mathf.Clamp(rb.transform.position.y / height, 0, 1);
    up = Mathf.Lerp(0f, height, up);
    rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * up);
}
```

Он работает, но когда объект поднимает в воздух, он начинает создавать люфт движения: вверх/вниз, вверх/вниз и со временем перестает это делать и успокаивается.
Как мне избавиться от этого люфта?

Метод `Lift()` объявляю в `Update()`.
`force` набирается по нажатию на кнопку:

```
private IEnumerator launch() {
    while (force < 25) {
        force += 0.1f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу в даном примере формулы движения обьекта. Зачем понадобилось аж три преобразоваания... ну ладно. Может у вас Clamp или  Lerp "пляшет"  и up стоит обвернуть в abs?

Comment: `1 - Mathf.Clamp(rb.transform.position.y / force, 0, 1);` - Сlamp - это ограничение верно? Вы берете у-координату, и из еденицы её вычитаете зачем? Что бы опустить вниз? Вот пока вы за грани Clamp не вышли - вас и трясет. А когда `у` больше чем 1 - тогда Clamp  стабильно отдаёт 1, и "тряска" прекращается.

Comment: @nick_n_a, подскажите как исправить. напишите ответ я выберу в качестве решения, тут же так принято ведь или я не правильно понял?

Comment: Я знаю математику, а unity - нет. Я вижу что первая формула вас должна трясти. Возможно вместо `1-формула` нужно писать просто `формула`. Именно знак минус - тянет вас вниз.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Если убираю что-либо, он либо вообще перестает взлетать, либо как бешеный взлетает и бесконечно поднимается.

Comment: @nick_n_a, однако, когда я `force` делаю 100, такого нет, он не люфтит, но мне 100 не надо, надо 8. ну 10 можно тоже ну не больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит следующее. Вы КАЖДЫЙ кадр ADD (добавляете) силу (которую вы даже не множите на drltaTime) и достигнув целевой высоты сила никуда не девается и он летит дальше, после чего падает и опускаясь ниже целевой высоты вы снова начинаете кормить объект импульсами силы. Отсуда он и выписывает синусойды.

```
float LiftSpeed = 1;
rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, (force-rb.transform.position.y)*LiftSpeed, rb.velocity.z);
```

Comment: немного не понимаю, куда это девать? Можете исправить мою функцию? Чтобы было наглядно,а то сложно понять, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Это и есть ваша функция (целиком).

Comment: Дико извеняюсь. я не с того проекта копирнул, обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста! Ваша формула поднимает махом, а мне надо не сразу а постепенно...

Comment: Ну так для этого и добавил LiftSpeed. Укажите значение поменьше... 0.1f или сколько вам нужно.

Comment: Разобрался... Я не туда подставлял и не то вобоще...Пришлось делать еще один цикл для этого...